# Ionic 4 error with function for deleting from local storage

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am making an app with Ionic v4 and I am making function to delete items that the user has added to favorites. I am getting an error when I run ionic serve in the command prompt.

I am very new to Ionic

My `delete.ts` file

```
 deleteFavorite(item: ItemSliding, id: number) {

    console.log('delete', id);
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      message: 'Do you want to delete this favorite cabin?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Delete cancelled')
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Delete',
          handler: () => {
            let loading = this.loadCtrl.create({
            });

            let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'Cabin ' + id + ' deleted successfully',
              duration: 3000
            });

            loading.present(); /*first error*/

            this.favservice.deleteFavorite(id)
              .subscribe(favs => {
              this.favorites = favs;
               loading.dismiss(); /* second error*/
               toast.present();  /* third error*/
            } , errMsg => {
              this.errMsg = errMsg;
               loading.dismiss();  /* fourth error*/
            });
          }
        }
      ]
    }).then(alert => alert.present());
    item.close();
  }
```

My error

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/pages/favorites/favorites.page.ts(57,21): error TS2570: Property 'present' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLIonLoadingElement>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
[ng] src/app/pages/favorites/favorites.page.ts(62,24): error TS2570: Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLIonLoadingElement>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
[ng] src/app/pages/favorites/favorites.page.ts(63,22): error TS2570: Property 'present' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLIonToastElement>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
[ng] src/app/pages/favorites/favorites.page.ts(66,24): error TS2570: Property 'dismiss' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTMLIonLoadingElement>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the official Ionic 4 documentation around AlertController. I think you are mixing up Ionic 3 docs within the new Ionic 4.

https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert

This is how a simple alertController is used in Ionic 4:

```
async presentAlert() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Alert',
      subHeader: 'Subtitle',
      message: 'This is an alert message.',
      buttons: ['OK']
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```